# Windows not showing in grub menu in dual boot in separate drives

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot

I've dual booted Debian with windows 10 in two separate ssd

Now everytime I boot my grub menu doesn't show windows at all
But if I switch to windows boot manager manually from bios it boots up windows.

I tried

```
Sudo update-grub
```

But no result whatsoever

What should I try next?

Comment: Do you have `os-prober` installed?  This is an extension for update-grub that helps grub search for other OSs.

Comment: Are both installed in same boot mode, both UEFI with gpt partitioning or both BIOS? The modes are not compatible and you can only boot from UEFI/BIOS memu if not in same boot mode.